# Принудительное выполнение участка кода из главного потока приложения

Tags: c#, многопоточность

В приложении используются backgroundworker'ы для решения некоторых задач. Подскажите, как правильно сделать так, чтобы определенный фрагмент кода всегда выполнялся только из главного потока приложения, даже при обращении к ним из потока worker'a?

Comment: А что должно (или что ожидается) происходить при обращении к такому участку кода из worker'а? пропускать его, блокировать...

Comment: Должно происходить выполнение данного кода из главного потока.

Comment: Добавлю, очень часто нужно стартовать второй поток (по типу fork) для чего нужно
th.Join(); // передать управление потоку

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для того чтобы возможно было выполнить код в некотором потоке, необходимо, чтобы сам этот поток был организован определённым образом, а именно в виде цикла обработки сообщений. В случае с WinAPI это достигается использованием цикла GetMessage - DispatchMessage. Если не использовать WindowsForms, подобный цикл можно организовать с помощью класса EventWaitHandle.

```
private readonly EventWaitHandle m_signal = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
private readonly Queue<Action> m_events = new Queue<Action>();
private volatile bool m_stop = false;

public void Start()
{
  // Создаём поток синхронизации. Все события будут обрабатываться в нём
  var th = new Thread(this.Run);
  th.Start();
}

private void Run()
{
  // Ожидаем сигнала о новом событии
  while (m_signal.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite))
  {
    // Если пришёл сигнал о прекращении работы - выходим
    if (m_stop)
      break;

    // Пока обрабатываются сообщения из очереди, добавлять их нельзя
    lock(m_events)
    {
      while (m_events.Count > 0)
      {
        try
        {
          // Достаём из очереди делегат и выполняем его
          m_events.Dequeue()();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          // Как-нибудь обрабатываем внешнее исключение
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Освобождаем ресурсы
  m_signal.Close();
}

public void Invoke(Action action)
{
  if (action == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

  // Добавляем событие в очередь и инициируем событие
  // Пока добавляем событие, приостанавливаем обработку
  lock(m_events)
  {
    m_events.Enqueue(action);
    m_signal.Set();
  }
}

public void Stop()
{
  // Инициируем сигнал о прекращении работы
  lock(m_events)
  {
    m_stop = true;
    m_signal.Set();
  }
}
```

Comment: Корректность этого кода во многом зависит от того как организован класс Action и работа с его объектами, сохраняемые в m_events.

Comment: Action - это стандартный делегат, без параметров и возвращаемого значения. По хорошему, m_events.Dequeue()() надо взять в try-catch, так как падение любого внешнего делегата приведёт к обрушению всего цикла обработки сообщений, но обработка исключений не будет способствовать улучшению наглядности примера.

Comment: Не знаю, что такое "стандартный делегат". Я не про try-catch, а про то что в делегатах может потребоваться синхронизация. У вас это нигде не упомянуто, а люди могут подумать что при любой реализации Action будет так работать.

Comment: 1. "Стандартный делегат" - это значит библиотечный тип, представляющий сигнатуру ссылки на метод. Соответственно, ни о какой "реализации" Action речи быть не может - это просто ссылка на произвольный метод определённой сигнатуры. То, что это не класс, должно быть очевидно по тому, что используется конструкция с двумя парами скобок: мы достаём из очереди ссылку на метод и тут же вызываем метод по этой ссылке.

2. Я всё-таки подправил код в соответствии со своей предыущей оговоркой. Теперь работать будет вне зависимости от того, что за метод будет передан извне.

Comment: Вот от такого подхода и появляются трудно отлавливаемые баги (поставил try-catch - причем не факт что верный - и сидит довольный). Еще раз повторю - за реализацией тех методов на которые ссылаются Action необходимо следить с точки зрения синхронизации. Хорошо, если эти методы не используются больше нигде (читай - ни в каком другом потоке), а если хотябы один из них будет вызван, то может потребоваться синхронизация этих потоков. Только это я имел ввиду. Так понятна мысль?

Comment: Там не случайно стоит lock (m_events). Оно гарантирует, что методы, выполняемые в заданном потоке, никогда не будут выполняться вместе с вызывающими потоками - они блокируют друг друга. Можно было бы для большей скорости переписать цикл обработки сообщений так, чтобы все сообщения, полученные из очереди, в синхронизированном контексте только копировались в локальный список, а сам этот список уже выполнялся без блокировки. А вообще, синхронизация - это отдельная задача, которую требуется решать в любом многопоточном приложении.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что стоит привести ещё один пример, на этот раз - как использовать интерфейс ISyncronizeInvoke. Этот интерфейс реализован в классе System.Windows.Forms.Control и предназначен специально для прокидывания любых делегатов в поток обработки цикла сообщений, в случае с контролами - цикла сообщений Windows.

Интерфейс содержит 4 члена.

Свойство InvokeRequired возвращает true, если текущий поток выполнения не является потоком обработки цикла сообщений. Если мы уже в потоке обработки цикла сообщений, свойство возвращает false.

Метод Invoke добавляет переданный ему делегат в цикл обработки сообщений и блокирует текущий поток до тех пор, пока цикл обработки сообщений не выполнит этот делегат. После того как делегат выполнен, метод возвращает управление со значением, которое вернул переданный ему делегат в процессе выполнения. Если делегат имел тип возвращаемого значения void, метод возвращает null.

Метод BeginInvoke добавляет переданный ему в качестве параметра делегат в цикл обработки сообщений и немедленно возвращает управление. Он возвращает объект типа IAsyncResult, который можно передать в качестве параметра последнему методу EndInvoke для ожидания завершения асинхронной операции. Простейший цикл обработки сообщений, который я привёл в предыдущем примере, обрабатывает события именно асинхронно, возвращая управление, не дожидаясь выполнения добавленного в очередь метода.

Для того чтобы добавить элемент в коллекцию так, чтобы само добавление обязательно происходило в потоке пользовательского интерфейса вне зависимости от того, откуда оно было вызвано, следует использовать такой паттерн:

```
private readonly ISynchronizeInvoke m_invoker;
private readonly BindingList<MyEntry> m_entries = new BindingList<MyEntry>();

// Конструктор с Dependency Injection, которому передаётся контрол либо форма
public BackgroundHandler(ISynchronizeInvoke invoker)
{
  if (invoker == null)
    throew new ArgumentNullException("invoker");

  m_invoker = invoker;
}

// 
public bool Add(MyEntry entry)
{
  // Если мы не в потоке обработки сообщений, 
  // метод добавляет в очередь сообщений ссылку на самого себя, 
  // ждёт завершения обработки и возвращает управление
  if (m_invoker.InvokeRequired)
    return (bool)invoker.Invoke(new Func<MyEntry, bool>(this.Add), new object[] { entry });

  // Поскольку мы сюда попали, мы уже в потоке обработки сообщений, 
  // делаем полезную работу - добавляем переданный элемент в список.
  // Возвращаемое значение - чисто для демонстрации, как его возвращать
  m_entries.Add(entry);
  return true;
}
```

Помещение кода синхронизации прямо в начало метода перед полезной работой очень облегчает читабельность кода, если полезная работа содержит много логики.

Answer (score -1):

Принудительно выполнить код в другом потоке нельзя - можно только передать управление другому потоку для выполнения этого (или другого) кода. Что и демонстрируют все примеры приведенные в ответах на вопрос. Функция (или "участок кода") вызванная в одном потоке не может перейти в другой поток.
Возможны только следующие паттерны:

- приостановить выполнение потока на этом участке кода пока он не выполниться в другом потоке (критические секции или семафоры)
- пропуск участка кода для некоторых потоков (реализуется разными способами)
- передача управления в другой поток с приостановкой (или без приостановки) выполнения данного потока (евенты, мъютексы)

Приведенные примеры Modus'а вариации третьего пункта списка + цикла сообщений windows. Но не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Я считаю ответы вполне исчерпывающими и подходящими для моей задачи.

PS Зачем спорить и отвергать решение другого участника, при этом рассуждая на абстрактные темы?

Answer (score -2):

Вы, видимо, не понимаете, как выполняются многопоточные приложения. Например, есть два потока:

- 1-й поток: работает функция F1(), вызывает F2()
- 2-й поток: работает функция G1(), вызывает F2()

В "общей" функции F2() требуется некоторая (какая именно зависит от функции) синхронизация, но поток "поменяться" с 2-го на 1-ый никак не может. Контекст другой.

Comment: Приведу пример того что я хочу: в потоке worker выполняется каких-либо условий, и в случае получения нужного результата вносятся изменения в некоторую коллекцию. По моему эти изменения вполне могут быть внесены из главного потока, контекст тут не при чем.

Comment: В таком случае вам необходимо функцию F2(), в которой подразумеваются описанные вам действия, запустить в новом потоке и ожидать события (по эвенту). Как только ваш worker устанавливает эвент и выполняется дальше. А поток с функцией F2() ловит эвент и выполняет свои действия. Но в главный поток все равно не передать, если конечно не ожидать в нем завершения worker'а.