# Событие в потоке

Tags: winforms, c#

Здравствуйте, подскажите мне, как привязать событие к потоку?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

[Организовать поток как цикл обработки сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4395/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)