# Постановка в очередь экземпляров асинхронного метода

Tags: c#

Приветствую!

В программе необходимо реализовать следующий механизм (объясняю на простом примере):

Имеется такой код:

```
    delegate void SomeDelegate(int x);
    int i;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SomeDelegate sd = ShowNumber; // Создаем делегат
        IAsyncResult asyncRes = sd.BeginInvoke(i++, null, null);//Запускаем метод
    }

    static void ShowNumber(int a)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000); //Ждем 3 секунды
        MessageBox.Show(a.ToString()); // Выводим сообщение
    }
```

В данном случае экземпляр метода асинхронно запускается и начинает свою работу после каждого нажатия кнопки. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы новый экземпляр запускался только тогда, когда предыдущий завершил свою работу (так же нужно учесть, что метод может быть вызван из разных мест).

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4395/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F): я уже давал решение такой задачи.